# Responsive website overlapping

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a website responsive; I am almost done with it, except that when I make the window smaller, the nav links overlap the logo on the left. Look at it [here](http://www.rockymountaindesigncollective.com/)
How do i make the nav bar move to under the logo when i re-size the window?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Couple different option.  Float the Nav right (the logo is floated left) so that when there's not enough room for them on the same line the nav will drop below.  Or, use some simple javascript to move the nav down when screen width is less than 735px.

Comment: The float right doesn't fix it. I think it has something to do with the positions of both being fixed maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play with your code and the first thing I spotted was the two #nav id's.
You should only have one unique id per page.

However, your main issue is the position fixed of the navigation items.
This is causing the nav to always just march on over the logo.
Position fixed ignores the document flow and places it wherever you put it.

You need to get the navigation back into the document flow
Change your nav items to relative and meddle with the top positioning.

You should place these in a new media query relating to your break points
You will also need to remove all those positioning styles. 
That should get you half way there.
I would help more but I've just been given a rum and coke so best to stop now.

Steve

Comment: thank you, yes it helped a lot. Another question for you. If you go to the site again and resize the window to cellphone size, some of the menu items move down. Is there another way without using the min-width property to not let this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Either move the logo down, or create some space above it and put the links in said space.

Comment: I thought about doing so but then the logo would overlap the slider. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change many of the `position` attributes along with the `float` properties - I played around with the CSS on the site, and this is what I changed:

```
#topBar {
    height: 300px;
}
.BODYcontainer {
    margin-top: 300px;
}
.container .columns {
    float: none;
}
.container .columns.logoBox {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
#companyNav {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, i implemented your ideas and it works well. Another question for you. If you go to the site again and resize the window to cellphone size, some of the menu items move down. Is there another way without using the min-width property to not let this happen?

Comment: Use `white-space: nowrap`.